# I keep getting this angular js error : Argument 'ExampleController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, controller

```html
<html>
<head>
    



<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/libs/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/libs/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/services/services.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/controllers/angularExampleController.js"></script>


<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>



    <title>Angular JS Tutorials</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="AngularExamples">

<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <ol>
        <li>Services Example for Modal Dialog <a href="" ng-click="testFunction()">Open Dialog </a></li>
    </ol>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the angularExampleController.js content, and the html where I am trying to bind to the controller

```js
(function(){

    var myApp = angular.module('AngularExamples', []);

    myApp.controller('ExampleController', function() {

    });
}());
```

```html
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <%@ include file="./imports/imports.jsp" %>
    <title>Angular JS Tutorials</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="AngularExamples">

<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <ol>
        <li>Services Example for Modal Dialog <a href="" ng-click="testFunction()">Open Dialog </a></li>
    </ol>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can't figure out what the issue is.  Any help is appreciated.

Edit : I am using AngularJS 1.3.3
Edit : Adding updated html.  But I also found the the issue, i had a "ng-app" directing in  tag and "ng-app=AngularExample" and that was causing the issue. i removed the directive from  tag, and that fixed it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

what is the output of imports.jsp? you sure it contains angularExampleController.js ?
personally it would help to see the html how it looks like when it was loaded in the browser and not a jsp version of it.

Answer (score 0):

But I also found the the issue, i had a "ng-app" directing in tag and "ng-app=AngularExample" and that was causing the issue. i removed the directive from tag, and that fixed it.